# Secure boot, Switch my main SSD to another PC

Tags: secure-boot, motherboard

My laptop needs to be sent for repair. I want to take out it's SSD (main, bootable) and plug it into another desktop machine in order to continue my work as as usual.

In theory [it should work](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-move-my-existing-Linux-hard-drive-to-another-PC-and-it-will-boot-and-run-perfectly-without-the-need-to-reinstall-everything), but there are 2 points that worry me:
A) secure boot is enabled

```
sudo mokutil --sb-state      
SecureBoot enabled
```

I will of course disable securre boot in the BIOS of the the desktop machine.
Should I disable secure in ubuntu also ?

B) there is a dual boot (windows10) installed (at boot, I select target via grub).
I do not plan to use windows10 on the desktop machine. Will it's presence cause any issue ?

Comment: I would not try to boot Windows, it may change things making it not work on laptop. You may have to reinstall grub. UEFI boots from entry in UEFI, to ESP to actual grub.cfg in your /boot (folder or partition). If UEFI boot entry not in desktop, or if original ESP not on drive, you may be not able to boot. I sent my laptop in, but had another full install with copy of most of my data on it in an external SSD (was M.2 SSD in USB adapter). I added grub entry on internal drive to boot external and used it.

Comment: I just swapped the machine, Windows booted automatically by accident on. First start . I can boot Ubuntu or grub, any advice?

Comment: Make sure you have good backups & a Windows repair/recovery flash drive as well as Ubuntu live installer to make repairs.If it works you should be ok, but backups can save a minor issue being converted to a major issue.